# Pilgrimage World with Consume 2x action--how many points?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

When consuming 4 goods on the Pilgrimage World using the 2x VP consume action, what is the total number of points that should be received: 6 or 7?

*The Card:* "Discard all remaining goods to gain that number -1 VPs"

*The Instructions:* "Discard all goods (possibly after using other consume powers) to gain VP chips equal to one less than the number of goods discarded"

*Consume Card:* "Receive twice as many VP chips as you would have normally received in this phase"

## My interpretation

> Six points. Determine how many victory points that you will receive normally, and then double them. You would normally receive 3 VP, so it should now be 6.

## My wife's interpretation

> Seven points. You would normally take 4 VP, then return one. So now you should take 8 and return one.

I'm smart enough to know that my wife's interpretation is right. But who's actually right?

Comment: Yeah, the second interpretation is wrong because it's added in a step of taking the VPs and then returning them. The consume ability doesn't say take 1VP for each, then return one; it says take one less than the number. You won't get 7 because you wouldn't have received 8 in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules say (page 6):

> Players who chose Consume: 2x VPs double the number of victory point
>   chips — but not any other effects — that their consume powers provide.

The consume power on Pilgrimage World defines the number of victory points you get for consuming a number of goods.  Consuming one good is zero points, two goods is one point, three goods is two points, and so on.  Then, the Consume 2x doubles the amount provided by Pilgrimage world.  In the situation you described, the player consuming 4 goods would get 6 points.